# If a capacitor value is given as an equation, how can it be written in LTspice?

Tags: capacitor, ltspice

For example: If a capacitance equals q·v·Ne·e<sup>vj</sup>, can I insert a simple capacitor and put its value as Q= (q·v·Ne·exp(vj))·x, where x is the predefined variable which means voltage across the capacitor?

Comment: Please explain the formula in detail.

Comment: If your expression for the capacitance includes the voltage across it (i.e. voltage dependent capacitance), then the answer is "No".  The nonlinear capacitor is a little tricky to deal with.  Fortunately, a similar question was asked recently and the information there can be applied to what you're trying to do too:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/661591/

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping your value with `{}` will allow dynamic evaluation..You can then use variables such as `q` and `x`. However, these variables much be defined, e.g. in a separate `.param q=1.602e-19 x=5` statement.

Comment: A reference supporting this: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-192.html